# Grails 1.3.3 and Functional Test plugin 1.2.7 issues

Tags: grails, functional-testing

Has anyone had any trouble getting Functional Test plugin working in Grails 1.3.3?  I've used it in previous projects with no problem, but just tried installing it into my latest project with no luck.

Installation seems to go fine.

Running the script:  grails create-functional-test XXXXX results in no test file.  Here's the output:

```
Running script /Users/dan/.grails/1.3.3/projects/connect/plugins/functional-test-1.2.7/scripts/CreateFunctionalTest.groovy
Environment set to development
     [copy] Copying 1 resource to /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect
    [unjar] Expanding: /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect/grails-shared-files.jar into /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect/grails-shared-files.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 resource to /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect
    [unjar] Expanding: /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect/grails-app-files.jar into /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/dan/dev/code/sterling/applications/grails/connect/trunk/connect/grails-app-files.jar
```

I tried creating a test script by had and pasted in the demo Twitter search test from the plugin page.  It failed as well.  Here's the error and stack trace:

```
functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestException: TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object twttr,Observer. (FunctionalTestCase.groovy#752)

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestException: TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object twttr,Observer. (FunctionalTestCase.groovy#752)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:205)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.get(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:526)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.get(FunctionalTestCase.groovy)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.doFollowRedirect(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:309)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.handleRedirects(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:496)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.makeRequest(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:490)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.get(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:526)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.get(FunctionalTestCase.groovy)
at functionaltestplugin.FunctionalTestCase.invokeMethod(FunctionalTestCase.groovy:201)
at AccessControlTests.testSearch(AccessControlTests.groovy:3)
```

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a bug with the functional test plugin with grails 1.3.x that according to Marc Palmer is being fixed now http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Functional-Test-plugin-doesn-t-work-td2265500.html

I tried installing the 1.3 version of the plugin but there were dependency issues.

The errors above are probably due to a lack of imports, maybe?

Comment: grails install-plugin functional-test 1.3-SNAPSHOT does install but the same problem seems to exist, create-functional-test doesn't create anything

Comment: Problem still persists with grails 1.3.7.